# Why are field and method resolution relative to superclasses different in the JVM?

Tags: java, inheritance, jvm, language-lawyer

Studying JVM internals and am a bit confused about this example, which features both an overriding method in a subclass and an instance variable being shadowed:

```
class CA extends Object {
    public int ivar;
        
    public void two() {
        ivar = 20;
        this.three();
    }
    
    public void three() {
        System.out.println("three called in CA");
        System.out.println(ivar);
    }
    
}
class CB extends CA {
    public int ivar;
    
    public void one() {
        ivar = 10;
        two();
    }
    
    public void three() {
        System.out.println("three called in CB");
        System.out.println(ivar);
        super.three();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CB cb = new CB();
        cb.one();
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
three called in CB
10
three called in CA
20
```

The method calls are entirely expected but I observe that the instance variable behaves differently-- when it's set and accessed within the implementation of the superclass, it's accessing the "shadowed" value.

I can't seem to find the discussion of how these behaviors work in the JVM spec, sections 5.4.3.2 and 5.4.3.3 (fields and methods, respectively). Both sections have very similar wording:

> If `C` declares a field with the name and descriptor specified by the field reference, field lookup succeeds. [...]

and

> [...] if `C` declares a method with the name and descriptor specified by the method reference, method lookup succeeds.

This suggests to me that the ivar behavior in the example above is sensible-- the class file for `CA` doesn't know about `CB`, so its field ref points to *its own version* of `ivar` and the JVM respects that when it sets and gets the value as it executes that class's method.

But the same would seem true for the overriding method, and I don't find the resolution algorithm to talk about "current object class" vs "implementing object class", etc. Am I looking in the wrong place? Can someone illuminate for me the design/implementation? Thanks!

Comment: I can add a little bit of _more_ confusion if you want : `Arrays.stream(CB.class.getFields()).map(Field::getName).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in 15.12 of the JLS, Method Invocation Expressions:

> Resolving a method name at compile time is more complicated than resolving a field name because of the possibility of method overloading. **Invoking a method at run time is also more complicated than accessing a field because of the possibility of instance method overriding.**

This is just a note, the actual rules for method invocation are very verbose and the part you want is 15.12.4.4. Locate Method to Invoke.

> If the method m of class or interface C is private, then it is the method to be invoked.
>
> Otherwise, overriding may occur. A dynamic method lookup, specified below, is used to locate the method to invoke. The lookup procedure starts from class R, the actual run-time class of the target object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. It looks like the narrow bit that explains the conventional behavior is the bit within that section that starts "The procedure for dynamic method lookup is as follows....". (Should I be surprised that this is found in the JLS and not the JVM spec? I would assume this behavior would want to be encoded in a notional generic VM)

Comment: JVM acts on bytecode, not the Java language so I'm not sure which you're looking for.  But the equivalent spec would be for `invokevirtual` which has similar requirements: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual. Section 5.4 only deals with linking, not actual invocation.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. And that part refers to section 5.4.6 which does cover superclass search (also 5.4.5). Thanks for your help. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.6

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your confusion -- what it outputted is exactly what I expected.

```
main calls
CB.one which sets CB.ivar to 10, then calls
CA.two which sets CA.ivar to 20, then calls
CB.three which prints CB.ivar (10), then calls
CA.three which prints CA.ivar (20)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the behavior of the standard runtime doesn't confuse me-- I'm trying to track down where the distinction in runtime behaviors is documented explicitly.